# rails way of doing if/else logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following code which seems to work fine:

```
  <%if group.employees.count > 0%>
    <td><%= link_to group.employees.count.to_s, {:action => 'index', :controller => 'employees'}, {:id=>group.id}%></td>
  <%else%>
    <td><%= link_to "Add Employee", {:action => 'new', :controller => 'employees'}%></td>        
  <%end%>
```

I'm just wondering how this can be written in more rails friendly way using unless?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would (with dylanfm's advice in the comment underneath) write it like this:

```
<% if group.employees.present? %>
  <td><%= link_to group.employees.count.to_s, employees_path, { :id=> "group_#{group.id}" }%></td>
<% else %>
  <td><%= link_to "Add Employee", new_employee_path %></td>        
<% end %>
```

Here I've used the `employees_path` and `new_employee_path` methods which are generated by using the routing helpers in *config/routes.rb*. You can read more about routing by reading [the Routing from the Outside In guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: I'm certainly not a fan of unless with an else. What about using `if group.employees.present?`. Calling #present? on an empty array in console appears to return false.

Comment: @dylanfm: You make a great point and I've updated the answer to show this.

Answer (score 2):

I consider it unreadable to use unless with else. Would be better to stick with what you have.

Answer (score 1):

You have an if-else branch (two possible different outcomes), so using `unless` would require you to change it to an unless-else branch, which is hard to understand.  If-else is the way to go in this situation.

If you only had a single condition, i.e.

```
if foo != 0
   do_something(bar)
end
```

It could be rewritten as

```
do_something(bar) unless foo == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
<% if group.employees.any? %>
 <td><%= link_to group.employees.count, employees_path, { :id=> dom_id(group) } %></td>
<% else %>
  <td><%= link_to "Add Employee", new_employee_path %></td>        
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use helper and content_tag to generate html instead of ugly erb grammar.

```
def foo
   if group.employees.count > 0
      content_tag(...)
   else
      content_tag(...)
   end
end
```

then in your view

```
<%= foo %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tumtu's way is the best, but I would even put the td tags outside the if statements. I would never use unless with else, and certainly is not a "rails way" to use unless.